# Got SQL error when retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from the firebase realtime database in recycler view using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. However every time I tried, I got an error like this:

**E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1473)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at aose.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):78)
        at aort.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):11)
        at aort.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):100)
        at aooq.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):11)
        at rxf.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):12)
        at rxf.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at scz.run(:com.google.android.gms@201817013@20.18.17 (020700-311416286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)**

This is my model class:

```
    int date;
    int value;

    public datapoint() {

    }

    public datapoint(int date, int value) {
        this.date = date;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

this is my adapter class for recycler view:

```
    private List<datapoint> datapointList;

    public MyAdapter(List<datapoint> datapointList){
        this.datapointList = datapointList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext ()).inflate(R.layout.list_data,parent,false) ;
        return new ViewHolder ( view );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            datapoint dp = datapointList.get ( position );
            holder.txtdate.setText ( dp.getDate () );
            holder.txtvalue.setText ( dp.getValue () );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datapointList.size ();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtdate,txtvalue;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
            txtdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.datetxt );
            txtvalue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.valuetxt );
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I retrieve data from firebase:

```
    private List<datapoint> datapointList;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private MyAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main2 );
        rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById ( R.id.myRecyclerview);
        rv.setHasFixedSize ( true );
        rv.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ) );
        datapointList= new ArrayList<> ();

        final DatabaseReference nm = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference().child ("fieldX").child ( "temperature" );
        nm.addListenerForSingleValueEvent ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists ()){
                    for(DataSnapshot npsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
                        datapoint d = npsnapshot.getValue (datapoint.class);
                        datapointList.add ( d );
                    }
                    adapter = new MyAdapter ( datapointList );
                    rv.setAdapter ( adapter );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }
}
```

I'm new to this, why did I get an SQL error? I didn't even use it. Does something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the complete error message **and** stack trace?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see any Firebase related code in that stack trace. Are you sure it's caused by the code you shared? If you *are* sure, I'd recommend uninstalling an reinstalling it to ensure any sqlite database it uses is cleared.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure these errors caused by the code I shared. I have created a new project with this code and I got the same error. Why did I get an SQL error even though I didn't even use it?

Comment: It just solved :)

Comment: Good to hear Septia. What solved the problem in the end?

Comment: I just put String.valueof in holder.txtdate.setText ( dp.getDate () );